# Can the XYZ tile naming convention be used for Geodetic (global-geodetic)?

Tags: tiles

I know that the XYZ convention is an alternative for the TMS convention for Mercator projection and in this configuration, it's also called the Slippy Maps naming convention.
Can the XYZ convention be used for the Geodetic projection? If so, is the conversion formula from TMS to XYZ the same for Geodetic and Mercator?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the Geodetic projection"?

Comment: @bugmenot123 The geodetic tiling convention. The tiles generated by `gdal2tiles.py -p geodetic`